# Why is my output equal to my input?

Tags: differential-equations

I tried to solve a system of differential equations with the code below:

```
DSolve[{Cos[θ[t]] + θ''[t] - Cos[θ[t]] Sin[θ[t]] ϕ''[t] == 0, 
  2 Cos[θ[t]] θ'[t] ϕ'[t] + Sin[θ[t]] θ''[t] == 0}, {θ[t], ϕ[t]}, t]
```

But I get the same output as my input.

What should I do?

Comment: Try using the second equation to eliminate `ϕ''` from the first.  DSolve might have an easier time with one equation.

Comment: That simply indicates Mathematica was unable to find a solution. If you can do with a numeric approximation you might get something usable from `NDSolve`.

Comment: fyi, Maple 18 gives this answer, I'll leave you to decide how useful this result  is ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqxvn.png)

Comment: it's rather annoying trend - some basic functions like solve, nsolve, dsolve, etc. often work better in other math. packages..

Comment: @funnypony If you look closely at Maple's output you'll see it isn't really a closed form solution.